# Install Product Out of Stock Subscription magento extenstion fetch error

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, stock, installation

Magento  Product Out of Stock Subscription extenstion
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription.html

[image]

Comment: Did you try to compile???

Comment: admin is not working

Comment: Check my answer. There i write how to do that without admin

Answer (score 0):

This extension package is not proper, So please check Data.php file in `app/code/local/BusinessKing/OutofStockSubscription/Helper` folder
with below code:

```
class BusinessKing_OutofStockSubscription_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

If Data.php file is not available please create.

Answer (score 0):

Open folder `include` and edit the config.php file. Comment all lines on that file.

Then go to `var` folder and delete `cache` folder.